# Can someone explain the purpose of CSS frameworks and why we use them?

Tags: css

So in class, we've been applying css frameworks like Bootstrap, Foundation, Normalize.css but I do not understand what the point is of using them. Can someone briefly explain WHY they are used? How am I supposed to know which framework to use? For example, let's say I made a basic HTML file for my blog and I want to style it. Would I need to use a framework? How would I know which to use? How is it different from just styling on my own from scratch? I know these seem like stupid, ridiculous questions but I just started learning CSS a month ago and do not understand what frameworks like Bootstrap, Foundation, Normalize, etc. are and the purpose of them. Someone please explain as if how they would explain to a little child so I understand? Thanks.

Comment: This is a question for http://www.quora.com :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=why+use+css+frameworks

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an opinion-based question, but in short: developers are lazy and it takes time to code sites that are mobile-ready, consistent across browsers, and are easy to manage as browsers get updated.

With frameworks, developers need not waste time figuring any of this out.

For example, with Bootstrap, using the *grid* system, it is possible to make mobile-ready sites with minimal `media` queries and complex CSS rules.

Using other people's code, which has been tested on production environments and is constantly being patched and updated, saves a lot of time and a lot of bugs down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of frameworks (in any language, not just CSS) as a bunch of existing reusable codes you can readily use for your own projects. They essentially make your life easier because you don't have to reinvent the wheel anymore. Simply put, frameworks are a bunch of tested reusable codes for common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to avoid having to make your CSS from scratch. There are a LOT of CSS activities that most people do over and over. If you look at a wide variety of sites, you'll notice similarities in the way information is presented. As a result, if you're going to be presenting information using one of those standard layouts, it's vastly easier to simply use a CSS framework than roll your own version.

Also, different browsers have different default CSS settings. Using a CSS framework will provide a CSS reset as part of what they do. This helps ensure that what you see in one browser is what will be seen in all browsers. This helps you spend more time building your site and less time trying to figure out why the display is different in a particular version of IE, for example.

Answer (score 0):

frameworks comes with lots of features like grid, components, typography along with good browser compatibility so you can simple use them instead of creating them from scratch. It totally based on project requirement that what framework you should use. Apart from bootstrap and Foundation there are more great out there created by few geeks.